# Using batch to change typed keys into other keys

Tags: batch-file

I would like to find a way to use batch to change the keys a user types into something else. I'm not sure if there is a way to do this in batch, so if there is a better way to do this please let me know. Basically, I would like to change what is typed into something else, meaning when the program is run, (for example) any time the user types the letter "a" it could replace it with the letter "b". I'm not sure if I can do this, and to clarify I do not want the answer given to me, just some guidance on how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48613341/edit) your question and add some code that you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean something like that in batch : - [Variable Edit/Replace](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

```bat
@echo off
Title Variable Edit/Replace
:Main
cls
echo Type a word ...
set /p "Input="
set "StrToFind=a"
set "NewStr=b"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set AfterReplaceInput=!Input:%StrToFind%=%NewStr%!
echo Before replace : !Input! 
echo After  replace : !AfterReplaceInput! 
echo(
echo Hit any key to try again with another word...
pause>nul
Goto Main
```

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.